# "Ни при чем", "не при чем" или "непричем"?

Tags: орфография, слитно-раздельно, не-или-ни

"Ни при чем", "не при чем" или "непричем"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Это трудный случай, который нужно запомнить. Правильно: "ни при чем".

Answer (score 1):

Е в таких местоимения пишется под ударением, здесь позиция безударная, поэтому И.

Answer (score 0):

отрицательные местоимения пишутся раздельно, если между приставкой и местоимением есть предлог: ни ПРИ чём, никого, но ни У кого.